# Load one library separate from bundle

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to use [this](https://www.vantajs.com/) library, but it depends on `THREE.js` already being loaded globally. I am using `typescript`, `webpack` and `webpack-dev-server`. Is it possible to make webpack load `THREE.js` as a separate script before the main bundle? I also need to use `THREE` in my own source code so I'd also want to exclude it from the main bundle altogether.

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    devtool: 'inline-sourcemap',
    mode: 'development',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        port: 4500
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/i,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.obj$/i,
                use: {
                    loader: 'file-loader'
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            }
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/dist'
    },
    plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'index.html',
        template: './src/index.ejs'
    })]
};
```

And my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es2015",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "src/types",
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@custom-modules/*": ["src/types/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "src/types"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably worth taking a CDN link to `three.js` and adding it into the html template you're binding to in `webpack`. It looks like this is your `index.ejs` file.

I'm not sure how you have this file structured, but in html it would look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

...
// globally add three.js to your site

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>

// put the rest of your scripts below
...

</head>

<body><!-- Your web--></body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by adding `three.js` to `externals` in my webpack config, and including it via CDN.